# EF: Cannot insert NULL to column

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the following table in the DB:

[image]

There are already apps in `Apps` table in the DB.
I present them to the end-user and he has to add items to `AppsToDomains` table

I'm trying to save an entity to that table:

```
private static void FillDomains(string[] domainsWls, EntityCollection<AppToDomains_V1> AppsToDomains, 
    Guid appGuid, Guid groupId ,bool isWhiteListed)
{
    foreach (var domain in domainsWls)
    {
        AppsToDomains.Add(new AppToDomains_V1()
                              {
                                  Domain = domain,
                                  IsWhiteListed = isWhiteListed,
                                  AppId = appGuid,
                                  GroupId = groupId,
                              });
    }
}
```

but get the following error:

> {"Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'ClientAppID', table 'MamDB.dbo.Apps'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.\r\nThe statement has been terminated."}

How can it be? as I don't add any row to the Apps table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to find out what is null. According to the exception you get, the problem does not have it source in the code you posted. When you save changes, you are saving all changes. also changes made by other code not visible in the current scope of you post.

Search for other code that is adding records to a table that has the column ClientAppID

Comment: I Edited my post. See above

Comment: @MichaelD I think you misunderstood the question. Elad is adding a record to the AppToDomains_V1 table, but the exception is that the Apps table doesn't accept nulls in a certain column. The question is where did the new record in the Apps table come from and how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

Based on your schema, it shows that you won't allow null on all of your fields, and that's why EF made it un-nullable. If you force to store null value in the EF, you will still have a problem when you save your data into your schema..

Answer (score 0):

One of the parameters you are passing in may have a NULL value.

```
 EntityCollection<AppToDomains_V1> AppsToDomains, 
    Guid appGuid, Guid groupId
```

You need to investigate these objects and see which is related to the `Apps` table and investigate null values.